# Github project card to branch creation to PR acceptance to done column

Tags: github

How can I achieve a workflow in GitHub such that when you create a card in todo column of a project, a branch will be created which you can start working on? When you PR the branch and merge, it will be automatically dragged into done column.

I've used VSTS before; I'd like to have something similar to that workflow.

Answer (score 0):

GitHub project board automation is very limited compared to other workflow tools. In particular, project board automation is intended to synchronize the project board columns with issue state, not to perform external actions upon card changes.

Therefore, you can configure that a card is moved to the done column when the issue is closed. You cannot automatically create a new branch when a card is created. Instead, consider whether you can create an external webhook that creates a branch (possible through the GH API) when card states change.